# Deep get item from json with default value in python

Tags: python

I have arbitrarily nested json. I want to get some value that is several keys deep and have no guarantee that any of the keys are present.

So, for example, I might want to get `value = json_dict['a'][1]['q']['e']` but at any point I could get a KeyError if `a`, `q`, or `e` don't exist, or an index out of bounds error if `json_dict['a']` has less than two items. If any of those conditions are true, I want `value` to be a default value, is there some way to do this is one or two lines without having to nest a bunch of if statements or `get` calls?

Comment: Looks like a pretty easy function to write. Give it a dict, a list of keys, loop over the list as you index into the subdicts and catch errors as necessary. You should at least be able to get started with this.

Comment: What means "If any of those conditions are two"? Does it mean at least two "keys" are missing?

Comment: @timgeb obviously I could write a function for it, I'm wondering if there's some built it function or syntactical trick for this kind of thing. It seems like it would be a fairly common use case.

Comment: @a_guest that was a typo, I corrected it.

Comment: There are cute tricks like [this](https://pastebin.com/pdqZ9dYH), but it's not very readable and has no error handling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put a simple pure python version of this together like:

```
def get_path(data, path, default=None):
    try:
        for item in path:
            data = data[item]
        return data
    except (KeyError, TypeError, IndexError):
        return default


nice_data = {'a': [None, {'q': {'e': 'Hello!'}}]}
bad_data = {'a': 6}
path = ['a', 1, 'q', 'e']

print('Good', get_path(nice_data, path))   # Hello!
print('Bad', get_path(bad_data, path))     # None
```

Not super fancy, but it works.

---

If you want to do something in one less line, with a bit more power, we can use something like ObjectPath (https://pypi.org/project/objectpath/):

```
from objectpath import Tree

def get_object_path(data, path, default=None):
    try:
        return Tree(data).execute(path)
    except (KeyError, TypeError, IndexError):
        return default


path = '$.a[1].q.e'
print('Good', get_object_path(nice_data, path))
print('Bad', get_object_path(bad_data, path))
```

We still have to put our own error handling on, and it's going to be much slower, but it can support all sorts of fancy queries (from the [docs](http://objectpath.org/)):

```
In weather readings find cities where temperature is higher than 25°C and the sky is clear.
$..*[@..temp > 25 and @.clouds.all is 0].name
```

Comment: Shouldn't you except `IndexError`s as well?

Comment: Yes. You definitely should. I'll amend the example. Thanks.